# Multiplying a multi index dataframe with single index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe "A" which is multi indexed shown below

```
                            LL           SK           Di         Co
Bracket         yr_wk               
1                121       2            2             4           3
                 122       3            6             5           4
                 123       3            2             6           2
                 124       2            5             5           3
                 125       3            5             6           3

2                121       4            7             1           6
                 122       1            5             1           7
                 123       3            9             6           4
                 124       5            1             5           6
                 125       8            7             7           2
```

Another dataframe "B" which is single index

```
            Factor
yr_wk   
121        0.98
122        1.045
123        0.92
124        0.99
125        0.95
```

I am trying to multiple the factor column of dataframe B with columns of A, grouped by the yr_wk column. Below is the resultant dataframe which I am trying to calculate

```
                            LL           SK           Di         Co
Bracket         yr_wk               
1                121       2*0.98       2*0.98        4*0.98      3*0.98
                 122       3*1.045      6*1.045       5*1.045     4*1.045
                 123       3*0.92       2*0.92        6*0.92      2*0.92
                 124       2*0.99       5*0.99        5*0.99      3*0.99
                 125       3*0.95       5*0.95        6*0.95      3*0.95

2                121       4*0.98       7*0.98        1*0.98      6*0.98
                 122       1*1.045      5*1.045       1*1.045     7*1.045
                 123       3*0.92       9*0.92        6*0.92      4*0.92
                 124       5*0.99       1*0.99        5*0.99      6*0.99
                 125       8*0.95       7*0.95        7*0.95      2*0.95
```

Below is what I tried but it is not working because I am messing up the index

```
C= A.multiply(B)
```

Comment: kindly provide the multiindex dataframes as a dictionary : ``df.to_dict()``. It is easier to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'yr_wk': [121, 122,123], 'LL': [2, 3, 3], 'SK':[2,6,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'yr_wk': [121, 122,123], 'Factor': [0.98, 1.045, 0.92]})
df = df.merge(df2, on = 'yr_wk')
for key in ['LL', 'SK']:
    df[key] = df[key] * df['Factor']
df = df.drop('Factor', axis=1)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
factor = dfA.merge(
    dfB, 
    how='left', 
    left_on=dfA.index.get_level_values(1), 
    right_index=True)['Factor']

result = dfA.mul(factor, axis=0)
print(result)
>>>
                  LL     SK     Di     Co
Bracket yr_wk                            
1       121    1.960  1.960  3.920  2.940
        122    3.135  6.270  5.225  4.180
        123    2.760  1.840  5.520  1.840
        124    1.980  4.950  4.950  2.970
        125    2.850  4.750  5.700  2.850
2       121    3.920  6.860  0.980  5.880
        122    1.045  5.225  1.045  7.315
        123    2.760  8.280  5.520  3.680
        124    4.950  0.990  4.950  5.940
        125    7.600  6.650  6.650  1.900
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**

use `broad casting`

```
df_A.unstack(0).mul(df_B['Factor'], axis=0).stack()

                  LL    SK      Di      Co
yr_wk   Bracket             
121     1         1.96  1.96    3.92    2.94
        2         3.92  6.86    0.98    5.88
122     1         3.13  6.27    5.22    4.18
        2         1.04  5.22    1.04    7.31
123     1         2.76  1.84    5.52    1.84
        2         2.76  8.28    5.52    3.68
124     1         1.98  4.95    4.95    2.97
        2         4.95  0.99    4.95    5.94
125     1         2.85  4.75    5.70    2.85
        2         7.60  6.65    6.65    1.90
```

**Second**

`swaplevel` and `sort_index` to make `desired output` (include **First Code**)

```
df_A.unstack(0).mul(df_B['Factor'], axis=0).stack().swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index()
```

output:

```
                  LL    SK      Di      Co
Bracket yr_wk               
1       121       1.96  1.96    3.92    2.94
        122       3.13  6.27    5.22    4.18
        123       2.76  1.84    5.52    1.84
        124       1.98  4.95    4.95    2.97
        125       2.85  4.75    5.70    2.85
2       121       3.92  6.86    0.98    5.88
        122       1.04  5.22    1.04    7.31
        123       2.76  8.28    5.52    3.68
        124       4.95  0.99    4.95    5.94
        125       7.60  6.65    6.65    1.90
```